Is it possible to sync up fast to the head of a substrate blockchain and then archive from that point on?
I'm dealing with a substrate based blockchain and I'd like to know if the current scenario is possible.
For my specific use case, I need to sync up with the head of the blockchain as quickly as possible, and from that point onwards, I'd like to keep all new synced blocks in local storage.
I read as much docs as I could, but it is not clear if that's even possible. I've been using flags like --sync=warp and --sync=fast, but if I start the node with these flags and I add also --pruning=archive, the binary complains that these flags together are not compatible.
Is there any way I could do this?
P.S. for reference, ethereum (using geth and lighthouse) allows this possibility https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/fundamentals/sync-modes:

It is also possible to create a partial/recent archive node where the node was synced using snap but the state is never pruned. This creates an archive node that saves all state data from the point that the node first syncs. This is configured by starting Geth with --syncmode snap --gcmode archive.

Would it be possible to do a --sync=fast and when reached the chain's head, stop and add the --pruning=archive flag?
Thanks!
